# Efforts and path to make distributed hardware resources based virtual emulated Linux machine?

Tags: operating-system

I am thinking of an idea about a big and very powerful emulated Linux based machine maybe something computer-net that have distributed resources around the world like RAM, Permanent Storage, Processing power, etc.

All computing tasks such as processing, memory etc can be fragmented to its very smallest forms and distributed them to all worker and resources nodes peer to peer directly from client and the results will be processed and combined by client itself no middle big server required.
Should not be like etherium type but more practical and cheap to implement and adopt to all.

Comment: I'd say the biggest issue with this distributed approach is confidentiality of the data. The moment any data is sensible, the model isn't functionnal anymore because calculation on encrypted data is not doable. If not encrypted, it could lead to massive leaks of private business and individual's information.